# CustomView doesn't show in scrollview , but scrollview is needed

Tags: android, view

**SOLUTION**

the solution was to add the onMeasure function and rescale my drawing in my test app it didn't need it but because of the scrollview in the quiz app it was required. this is the code i added:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, resolveSize(800, heightMeasureSpec));

}
```

**QUESTION**

I'm making a quiz app and one of the questions has a map in it where the user needs to touch the stations he has to take, when pressed the stations get highlighted. I've made a customview for this in a test project. There it works fine. but now i want to get that custom view into my quiz app by programatically adding it to a linear layout, but the problem is that is doesn't show.

this is the custom view:

public class BrushView extends View {

```
private Paint brush = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
public Button btnEraseAll;
public LayoutParams params;
private Canvas mcanvas;
float mX;
float mY;
TextView mTVCoordinates;
ArrayList<Coordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
Coordinates coord;
boolean alreadySelected = false;
int pos;


@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public BrushView(Context context) {

    super(context);
    brush.setAntiAlias(true);
    brush.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    brush.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    brush.setStrokeWidth(10f);

/*  params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);*/

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
        mX = event.getX();
        mY = event.getY();

        Log.d("coordinates","x="+mX+ " y="+mY);

        if (mTVCoordinates != null) {
            mTVCoordinates.setText("X :" + mX + " , " + "Y :" + mY);
        }
        if ((mX > 200 && mX < 240) && (mY > 210 && mY < 235)) {
            // Draw the circle at (x,y) with radius 15
            mX = 230;
            mY = 220;
            if (coordinates.isEmpty()) {
                brush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                path.addCircle(mX, mY, 15, Path.Direction.CW);
                coord = new Coordinates(mX, mY, path, Color.GREEN);
                coordinates.add(coord);
                path = new Path();
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
                    Coordinates c = coordinates.get(i);
                    if (c.getX() == mX && c.getY() == mY) {
                        alreadySelected = true;
                        pos = i;
                    } 
                }
                if (alreadySelected) {
                    coordinates.remove(pos);
                } else{
                    brush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                path.addCircle(mX, mY, 15, Path.Direction.CW);
                coord = new Coordinates(mX, mY, path, Color.GREEN);
                coordinates.add(coord);
                path = new Path();
                }
            }
        }
        if ((mX > 330 && mX < 360) && (mY > 125 && mY < 150)) {
            // Draw the circle at (x,y) with radius 15
            mX = 340;
            mY = 140;
            if (coordinates.isEmpty()) {
                brush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                path.addCircle(mX, mY, 15, Path.Direction.CW);
                coord = new Coordinates(mX, mY, path, Color.GREEN);
                coordinates.add(coord);
                path = new Path();
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
                    Coordinates c = coordinates.get(i);
                    if (c.getX() == mX && c.getY() == mY) {
                        alreadySelected = true;
                        pos = i;
                    } 
                }
                if (alreadySelected) {
                    coordinates.remove(pos);
                } else{
                    brush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                path.addCircle(mX, mY, 15, Path.Direction.CW);
                coord = new Coordinates(mX, mY, path, Color.GREEN);
                coordinates.add(coord);
                path = new Path();
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        postInvalidate();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    // Force a view to draw again
    postInvalidate();
    return false;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    alreadySelected = false;
    Bitmap srcBitmapLocal = GlobalStatic.img;
    canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmapLocal, 0, 0, brush);
    for (Coordinates c : coordinates) {
        brush.setColor(c.getC());
        canvas.drawPath(c.getP(), brush);
    }
}
```

and this is part of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    ctx = getBaseContext();
    activity = this;
    statementsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutUp);
    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn_previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new ButtonHandler());
    btn_previous.setOnClickListener(new ButtonHandler());
    GlobalStatic.text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    GlobalStatic.text.setText(GlobalStatic.text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
    countDownTimer.start();

    setScreen(teller);
}
```

the part were i try to add the custom view
    private void showStatementsAndAnswer(int id) {

```
    String statement_text;
    Bitmap statement_img;
    int statement_displayType;
    ArrayList<Statements> statementPerQuestion;
    ArrayList<Answer> answersPerStatement;

    statementPerQuestion = DbAccess.getStatementsPerQuestions(id);
    totalStatementsPerQuestion = statementPerQuestion.size();

    s = statementPerQuestion.get(statementcount); // get statement at position b

    statement_text = s.getText();
    statement_img = s.getImage();
    statement_displayType = s.getDisplaytype();

    // show the elements that are not null
    if (statement_text != null) {
        TextView S_text = new TextView(this);
        S_text.setText(statement_text);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 40, 0, 35);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        S_text.setLayoutParams(params);
        S_text.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.BOLD));
        S_text.setTextSize(18);
        statementsLayout.addView(S_text);
    }
    if (statement_img != null && statement_displayType != 5) {
        ImageView S_img = new ImageView(this);
        S_img.setImageBitmap(statement_img);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 25;
        S_img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        statementsLayout.addView(S_img);
    }
    //here is where i try to get my custom view shown!!!
    if(statement_img != null && statement_displayType == 5){
        GlobalStatic.img = statement_img;
        BrushView S_map = new BrushView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        S_map.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        statementsLayout.addView(S_map);
    }

    statementId = s.getId(); // add the statementID's to an array to get the answers later

    answersPerStatement = DbAccess.getAnswerPerStatement(s.getId()); // get possible answers per statement

    // show answer depending on what the displaytype is.
    if (statement_displayType == 1) {
        makeSpinner(1, answersPerStatement);
    } else if (statement_displayType == 3) {
        makeRadioButtons(answersPerStatement);
    } else if (statement_displayType == 2) {
        TextView[] views = new TextView[answersPerStatement.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < answersPerStatement.size(); i++)
        {
            views[i] = new TextView(this);
            a = answersPerStatement.get(i);
            views[i].setText(a.getText());
            views[i].setId(a.getId()); // give the rb the same id as the answer in the db
            views[i].setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.NORMAL));
            views[i].setTextSize(20);

        }

        populateText(statementsLayout, views, getBaseContext());
    } 
}
```

im pretty new to android and never worked with customviews before so example code would help alot.

thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE**:

it looks like the scrollview in my xml is the thing that is causing the fact taht it isn't shown but i need that scrollview anyone any options or thought on how to solve that?

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: I solved it, but i can't seem to find a way of setting the question to solved.

Comment: @kicked11 Post your solution as an answer and click the checkmark on the left to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: oke thanks i just did but i can't click the mark myself today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself but I'm leaving it on here for other people.

***SOLUTION***

the solution was to add the onMeasure function and rescale my drawing in my test app it didn't need it but because of the scrollview in the quiz app it was required. this is the code i added:

```
@Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, resolveSize(800, heightMeasureSpec));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added your container view to the custom view. 
like addView(statementsLayout) after adding all view to statementsLayout.

Comment: Thanks for answering! but i managed to sovle it as I edited in my question. I did add it. It was the scrollview that was causing the view to not show. so after adding in the onMeasure function it work in my scrollview.